# Multiplying decimals and integers ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Seems pretty simple, but then nothing is.

I have two values:

```
t.integer  "quantity"
t.decimal  "unit_price",         :precision => 7, :scale => 2
```

I want to multiply quantity by unit_price in an each (invoice) loop:

```
invoice.quantity * invoice.unit_price
```

This causes the following error:

```
undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass
```

Do I have to convert the values first or is there something trivial I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
invoice.quantity
```

Is returning `nil`.

You can tell by the error message

```
undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass
```

You are trying to execute the method `*` on an instance of `NilClass`

Check this out as an example

```
> nil * 5
=> undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: When I output just "invoice.quantity" on it's own it returns a value though?

Comment: Where? In a view? Rails has a way of hiding things from you.

Comment: Yep, in the view. Perhaps I should go step back and perform the calc in the controller first. Thanks

Comment: @user1137277: I'd recommend wrapping that calculation in a method on the model instead.

Comment: It was returning nul for one row which causing the error, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your migration, add default values to those columns.

```
t.integer  "quantity", :default => 0
t.decimal  "unit_price",         :precision => 7, :scale => 2, :default => 0
```

That way, you won't get this error even if you haven't yet set these values for a particular record, which is what I suspect is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

It just means that `invoice.quantity` is nil.

You can handle this in your multiplication by doing `invoice.quantity.to_i * invoice.unit_price` or it may be more appropriate to check for it before doing the calculation.

Comment: When I output just "invoice.quantity" on it's own it returns a value though?

Comment: I tried your example but then get the following error: "nil can't be coerced into Fixnum"

Comment: That would suggest that invoice.unit_price is nil also. You could use `invoice.unit_price.to_f` but it would be worth checking for nil first.

Comment: You're right, that prevented the error but then the output was 0, which obviously means that both values are nil. What I can't understand is that when I output these in the view individually they both return values

Comment: 10 years later and i run in the exact same problem with decimals multiplication. any possibility you are still active and remember the solution?